# Understanding seam filter url-pattern and possible conflicts

Tags: xmlhttprequest, servlet-filters, seam, multipartform-data

I made a custom editor plugin, in a Seam 2.2.2 project, which makes file upload this way:

1) config the editor to load my specific xhtml upload page;

2) call the following method inside this page, and return a javascript callback;

```
public String sendImageToServer()
    {
        HttpServletRequest request = ServletContexts.instance().getRequest();
        try
        {
            List<FileItem> items = new ServletFileUpload(new DiskFileItemFactory()).parseRequest(request);
            processItems(items);//set the file data to specific att
            saveOpenAttachment();//save the file to disk
        }
        //build callback
```

For this to work I have to put this inside components.xml:

```
<web:multipart-filter create-temp-files="false"  
                  max-request-size="1024000" url-pattern="*"/>
```

The attribute create-temp-files do not seems to matter whatever its value.
But url-pattern has to be "*" or "*/myUploadPage.seam", any other value makes the item list returns empty. Does Anyone know why?

This turns into a problem because when I use a url-pattern that work to this case, every form with enctype="multipart/form-data" in my application stops to submit data. So I end up with other parts of the system crashing.
Could someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve my problem, I changed the solution to be like Seam multipart filter handle requests:

```
ServletRequest request = (ServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
    try
    {
      if (!(request instanceof MultipartRequest))
      {
         request = unwrapMultipartRequest(request);
      }

      if (request instanceof MultipartRequest)
      {
         MultipartRequest multipartRequest = (MultipartRequest) request;

         String clientId = "upload";
         setFileData(multipartRequest.getFileBytes(clientId));
         setFileContentType(multipartRequest.getFileContentType(clientId));
         setFileName(multipartRequest.getFileName(clientId));
         saveOpenAttachment();
      }
    }
```

Now I handle the request like Seam do, and do not need the web:multipart-filter config that was breaking other types of request.